# Как запустить функцию вместе с ботом aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram-2.x

Делаю очередного бота и понадобилось запускать асинхронную функцию вместе с запуском бота, функция с условием while True, нужно чтобы бот работал и функция также, не мешая работе бота. Пишу бота на версии aiogram 2.23.1, ранее реализовывал ранее таким образом: https://imgur.com/a/QxxhnAQ . Но сейчас при таком же коде, выдает предупреждение: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
Оно как бы и работает, но мешает работе бота и бот не реагирует ни на что, если знает, другой вариант кода, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так запусти свою функцию как отдельный скрипт, в чём проблема?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1561881/470333